# How could I get a part of live view on screen

Tags: python, view, crop, live, auto

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
count = 0
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', gray)
    ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    cv2.imwrite('capture.png', thresh
```

Hello I am using above code to see live view on a Python program.  I would like to have only a part of the live view but I couldn't do that.

Could anyone comment on how I could do that?

[Not Cropped View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3Pvc.jpg)

I would like to see only red squared area on live view.

Comment: you can crop the region of interst (red area) if you have bounding box cordinates

Comment: thank you that's it :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access your front webcam?

Try

- `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)` instead of `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)`
- `cv2.imwrite('capture.png', thresh)` instead of `cv2.imwrite('capture.png', thresh`

make sure to add:

```
if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

after `cv2.imwrite()` or your screen will freeze up.

(I'm also not sure what your `ret,thresh=cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)` line is trying to do. I think that might be done wrong)